# How to create an admin inline for a recipe entry

Tags: django, django-admin

I am creating a minimal viable product of a recipe application. I would like to leverage the admin site to create a diary entry that, consists of a recipe, that consists of ingredients with amounts and quantities. I read that inlines are possible. However, I have not successfully been able to implement one.

```
class Meal(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Meal")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Meals")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Measurement(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Measurement")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Measurements")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Ingredient(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Ingredient")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Ingredients")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Recipe(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Recipe")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Recipes")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("RecipeIngredient")
        verbose_name_plural = ("RecipeIngredients")

 
class Diary(models.Model):
    
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)    
    occured_at = models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Diary")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Diaries")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, you can use StackedInline or TabularInline. Here is the code for general StackedInline. TabularInline works in the same way.

**#admin.py**

```
class Class_1(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Model_1
    
class Class_2(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Model_2     

class Class_3(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [Class_1,Model_2]

admin.site.register(Model_Name, Class_3)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is getting me closer but still an error.

<class 'apps.food.admin.Class_1'>: (admin.E202) 'food.Recipe' has no ForeignKey to 'food.RecipeIngredient'.

<class 'apps.food.admin.Class_3'>: (admin.E104) 'apps.food.models.RecipeIngredient' must inherit from 'InlineModelAdmin'.

Comment: If you are showing model A in model B in the Django admin panel then you have to set model A as a child of model B using Foreign Key.